# Can commands be used to concatenate NBT strings?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a grid of buttons representing letters and numbers on a wall. The player can press these buttons to enter text into a machine. Each letter is typed by adding a string with that letter to the end of an NBT array. For example, when the 'L' button is pressed, this command is run:

```
data modify storage chatbot:main CurrentEntry append value "L"
```

For example, a completed entry for the phrase `Life is a bowl of cherries` might look like this:

```
{CurrentEntry:["L","i","f","e"," ","i","s"," ","a"," ","b","o","w","l"," ","o","f"," ","c","h","e","r","r","i","e","s"]}
```

I am going to need to concatenate each value in the query array in order to produce a single string with the full query to use.

Concatenating strings in Minecraft is likely not an easy task. How should this be approached? Let's start with a simple example:

```
{String1:"Life is a ",String2:"bowl of cherries"}
{ResultString:"Life is a bowl of cherries"}
```

I have tried `/data modify ... append`, but it can only be used for adding to lists, not adding to strings.

**See also:** [Splitting NBT strings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/378345/250180)

Answer (score 7):

## Original answer

> This answer *may* be out of date.

**TL;DR: Vote for MC-183054 if you want this.**

I've had a [discussion](https://github.com/McTsts/Minecraft-String-Utilities/issues/8) with the developer of [Minecraft String Utilities](https://github.com/McTsts/Minecraft-String-Utilities), the data pack that lets you turn NBT strings into a list of characters so that each individual character can be manipulated. This discussion revealed that string concatenation is not possible, and neither is turning the character arrays produced by the data pack back into single strings.

However, it was recently brought up that there is a known method that is being blocked by a bug that must be fixed. If the bug is fixed, this will mean that strong concatenation will finally be possible and open up a whole new realm of what's possible with Minecraft commands.

The method in question involves structure blocks and endermen, specifically, their ability to pick up and place blocks all by themselves.

Notice the NBT format for [structure blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Structure_Block). The `author` tag contains the unflattened version of the entity that placed it. Which means, we can rename an enderman to an `nbt` JSON component, give it a structure block, wait for it to place it, and check its `author` tag for the unflattened string.

Unfortunately, as stated above, there is a bug preventing this method from working. The bug in question is [MC-183054](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-183054).

Have you noticed that an enderman can't spawn a Wither by placing the skulls on? Turns out that applies to all other block updates, including the one that sets the structure block's `author` tag.

So, we're almost able to unflatten strings. If you want to be able to do this, please vote for the bug to be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

as of 1.19.4 you can splice strings with the data command, so you should be able to use enchant flattening then splice the output at certain indices to get the desired result.

I think

Comment: You think? What do you base this on, then?

Comment: I'm with Joachim on this one. Could you look into whether this is correct yourself or find a source that backs this?

Comment: https://github.com/kronosta/minecraft_string_concat

i did not make this.

Comment: It is also outdated, so it uses the signs text1 field instead of front_text.messages[0], but that is an easy fix.

Comment: If you dont want to mess with editing the data pack, do this setup:
0, 0, 0: sign
0, 0, 0: armour stand
0, 2, 0: command block facing up:
data modify block ~ ~-2 ~ front_text.messages[0] set value '{"nbt":"input","storage":"concat","interpret":true}'
0, 3, 0: repeat command block up:
data modify entity @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand, limit=1, sort=nearest] CustomName set from block ~ ~-3 ~ front_text.messages[0]
0, 4, 0: rep cmd face up:
enchant @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand, limit=1, sort=nearest] minecraft:aqua_affinity

Comment: then have
0, 5, 0: same:
data modify storage minecraft:concat output set string block ~ ~-1 ~ LastOutput 91 -38
sory ran out of charactors.
to use store an array of strings in minecraft:concat.input, get the concatenated result from concat.output