# Can commands be used to split or splice NBT strings?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map where two players are given halves of a message, and then have to travel through their own separate courses to meet at a central point, where the message must be put together and submitted as a whole within a certain time limit to win the game.

In order to make this function, the string with the message must be split in half before being sent to the players. I need to find a way to split a string at a certain index.

For example:

```
{String:"Life is a bowl of cherries",Index:10b}
```

needs to become:

```
{ResultStringA:"Life is a ",ResultStringB:"bowl of cherries"}
```

I do not mind the relation of the index number to the split point, but I need to ensure that it can be dynamically manipulated, such as with commands.

Alternatively, if a simple split method does not exist, but a method to extract a substring from an NBT string does, that could also be used to achieve the desired effect.

**See also:** [Concatenating NBT strings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/378308/250180)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Minecraft Java v1.19.4, a new option has been added to the `/data modify` command. When specifying a new value for a tag, these are the current options:

- Existing: `value` – To specify the new value directly within the command.
- Existing: `from` – To specify that the new value should be fetched from another source.
- **New:** `string` – To specify that the new value is a string, should be fetched from another source, *and* that a specified substring of said source should be extracted.

The syntax of these options are as follows:

```
value <value>
from (block <sourcePos>|entity <source>|storage <source>) [<sourcePath>]
string (block <sourcePos>|entity <source>|storage <source>) [<sourcePath>] [<start>] [<end>]
```

Samples:

```
value "hello"
from entity @e[type=marker,limit=1,sort=nearest] CustomName
string storage test:main MyString 0 4
```

The indices of `string` index from 0 being the first character. The character at the start index is included, but the character at the end index is not.

However, the indices of `string` are not dynamic. This is a limitation in that the start and end indices cannot be set through scoreboard values or the like. The most common workaround is a function tree, but this can be impractical given the large number of possible indices.

Further study will be required to discover the best workarounds for dynamic indices.